# How can I get two variables to hold the amount of higher than and lower than guesses?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am creating a game in which the computer selects a random number 1-10
Then the user guesses the number until they get it right.
The trouble I am having is that when the users enter the wrong answer the variables high or low should be updated, but it just continues looping until the user does enter the right answer. Which causes high and low to always be at 0.

Any ideas? I know there is probably something wrong with the way I am looping?

Any pushes in the right direction would be great!

```
# module to generate the random number
import random
def randomNum():
    selection = random.randint(0,9)
    return selection

# get the users choices
def userGuess():
    correct = True
    while correct:
        try:
            userPick = int(input('Please enter a guess 1-10: '))
            if userPick < 1 or userPick >10:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('Please only enter a valid number 1 - 10')
            continue
        return userPick

# define main so we can play the game
def main():
    correctNum = randomNum()
    guess = userGuess()
    high = 0 
    low = 0
    if guess != correctNum:
            print('uhoh try again!')
            guess=userGuess()
    elif guess > correctNum:
            print('That guess is too high!')
            high = high + 1
    elif guess < correctNum:
            print('That guess is too low')
            low = low + 1
    else:
            print('You win!')
    # the outcome of the game:
    print('Guesses too high:', high)
    print('Guesses too low:',low)
    print('Thank you for playing!')
main()
```

Comment: You have redundant criteria in your `if` block.  `guess != correctNum` already encompasses `guess > correctNum` and `guess < correctNum`, so you never hit either `elif` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your `main` function :

```
def main():
    correctNum = randomNum()
    guess = userGuess()
    high = low = 0 # nifty way to assign the same integer to multiple variables
    while guess != correctNum: # repeat until guess is correct
        if guess > correctNum:
            print('That guess is too high!')
            high = high + 1
        else:
            print('That guess is too low')
            low = low + 1
        print('Try again!')
        guess=userGuess()

    print('You win!')
    # the outcome of the game:
    print('Guesses too high:', high)
    print('Guesses too low:',low)
    print('Thank you for playing!')
```

Also, be careful with `random.randint(0,9)` : this will give a number between 0-9 (including 0 and 9, but never 10)!

You want to be doing `random.randint(1, 10)`

Comment: AH thank you for the reminder on the 0,9! We have to declare that we want to start at 1 and end at 10!

Answer (score 0):

```
    # module to generate the random number
import random
def get1to10():
    selection = random.randint(1,10)
    return selection
# get the users choices
def userGuess():
    correct = True
    while correct:
        try:
            userPick = int(input('Please enter a guess 1-10: '))
            if userPick < 1 or userPick >10:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print('Please only enter a valid number 1 - 10')
            continue
        return userPick
# define main so we can play the game
def main():
    correctNum = get1to10()
    guess = 0
    high = 0 
    low = 0
    # use a while loop to collect user input until their answer is right
    while guess != correctNum:
        guess = userGuess()
        # use if statements to evaluate if it is < or >
        if guess > correctNum:
            print('This is too high!')
            high = high + 1
            continue
        # use continue to keep going through the loop if these are true
        elif guess < correctNum:
            print('this is too low!')
            low = low + 1
            continue
        else:
            break
    

    # the outcome of the game:
    print('----------------------')
    print('Guesses too high:', high)
    print('Guesses too low:',low)
    print('The correct answer was:', '*',correctNum,'*', sep = '' )
    print('Thank you for playing!')
    print('---------------------')
main()
```

I found this solution to work well for what I needed!
Thank you everyone who answered this post!

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a dictionary:

```
guesses = {'Higher': [],
           'Lower': [],
           'Correct': False,
           }  # A Dictionary variable


def add_guess(number, correct_number):
    if number > correct_number:
        guesses['Higher'].append(number)
    elif number < correct_number:
        guesses['Lower'].append(number)
    else:
        guesses['Correct'] = True

    return guesses


add_guess(number=5, correct_number=3)  # Higher
add_guess(10, 3)  # Higher
add_guess(2, 3)  # Lower
# Correct is False, and higher has the numbers (10, 5) while lower has the numbers (2)
print(guesses)
add_guess(3, 3)  # Correct should now be True

print(guesses)
```

This, of course, isn't the entire code but should point you in the right direction. There is a ton of resources on python dictionaries online.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding!
I responded to this post with the solution that I was able to come up with